# Angular 2 View will not update after variable change in subscribe

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a problem where my view will not change when I update my variable in my observable subscription. I am trying to show a loading spinner while I wait for a response from my backend and then display the response, but the spinner won't hide. My subscription looks like this:

```
this.isRequesting = "true";
this.questionService.onSubmit(form, this.questions).subscribe( (value) => {
        this._ngZone.run( () => {
             this.fileLocation = JSON.stringify(value);
             console.log(this.fileLocation);
            this.isRequesting = "false";
            console.log(this.isRequesting);
        });
    });
```

And my html for this component looks like this:

```
<spinner *ngIf="isRequesting=='true'"></spinner>
```

I can see that isRequesting changes to "false" in my console after I get a response back from the backend (Springboot), but the view still does not change. The spinner was from [SpinKit](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/) and I modified this [tutorial](https://manuel-rauber.com/2016/01/05/angular-2-spinner-component/) for my spinner to work.

I have tried:

1. The way in the tutorial (with stopRefreshing() in the error and complete parameters of the observable)
2. ngZone to force my view to update.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get my view to update or any way to get my spinner to hide after I get a response from my backend?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

are you seeing any error on console?
This could be due to fact that angular is not running change detection after you have made updates to value. 
I think you don't need `ngZone.run` as it will run code outside the angular zone.

```
this.questionService.onSubmit(form, this.questions).subscribe( (value) => {
            this.fileLocation = JSON.stringify(value);
            console.log(this.fileLocation);
            this.isRequesting = "false";
            console.log(this.isRequesting);
    });
```

If due to some reason you need to run this outside Angular zone, then you should inform angular to run a change detection cycle by either of this method.

- just wrap update of isRequesting in set timeout

  ```
  setTimeout( () => this.isRequesting = "false", 0);
  ```
- invoking change detection manually

  ```
  import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core'
  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){}

  this.questionService.onSubmit(form, this.questions).subscribe( (value)=> {
      //existing code
      console.log(this.isRequesting);
      this.ref.detectChanges();
  });
  ```

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. I had no errors and had tried the first solution, but your solution using `ChangeDetectionRef` made me realize I had set my `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush`. That was the issue! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Had the same issue with onPush. Observables were firing in console.log but not in template. Disabled onPush and now tempalte is updated.

Comment: It's `ChangeDetectorRef`, not `ChangeDetectionRef`

Comment: I had the animations problem. The solution was removing ChangeDetectorRef and doing what OP was trying: wrap it in ngZone.run.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal ngZone.run() runs Code IN Angular zone, not outside of it -> see https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run 
 It is there, as far as I understood it, to have code that is running outside the Angular zone return back to the Angular zone, so to speak. To run code outside, you would call ngZone.runOutsideAngular()

Comment: Thank you. The Angular docs doesn't properly explain this IMO. But this makes clear sense to me...

Answer (score 21):

You can also try this solution: [Guide from Thoughtram](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)

Short version:

```
 import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
    ...
    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
    ...
    ... .subscribe( () => {
           <yourstuff>
           this.cd.markForCheck();
        }
```

and you are good.

Background: when changing a value via .subscribe() angular does not notify that it should run changedetection. So you need to run it yourself.

Comment: Why would a value changed via `subscribe` not trigger change detection? Is this something I could manage with the "scheduler" notion in rxjs?

Comment: Is there a documentation to know why changing a value via .subscribe() angular does not kicks its change detection?

Comment: I'm amazed that there is not an answers to these last 2 comments. Like it has to be documented. Anyone managed to find it in docs?

Answer (score 3):

You can switch (on/off) template updating via changeDetection. You have to put your choice of strategy into component definition. You can choose Default or OnPush strategy.

```
@Component({
    selector: '...............',
    templateUrl: '.......html',
    styleUrls: ['..........scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using it in expression `*ngIf` remember `*ngIf = false` will not work as expression you need to add

```
<ul *ngIf=" somefunction(x) ? false: true">
```