# Getting updated values from Observable's subscription

Tags: angular, observable

I have noticed something about Observables in Angular 2 that I cannot explain and hope a good sould sheds light on me.

My understanding was that when subscribing to an Observable you have basically two strategies to consume the value it emits:

stream combined with async pipe, as in:

```
myTextSubscription$ = SomeObservable.subscribe();

{{ myTextSubscription$ | async }}
```

or extract the value and bind it from within the subscribe handler:

```
myTextSubscription$ = SomeObservable.subscribe(text => this.text = text);

{{ text }}
```

Well, the problem is that I have already tried a couple of times to use the latter approach and I never managed to get the `text` value updated, unless I invoke `this.cdRef.markForCheck()` within the handler. I guess invoking the changeDetection manually should not be required for such a basic scenario - at least I haven't seen that used in any of screencasts or tutorials.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? Is it my wrong understanding of the method, or is it perhaps a bug in Angular 2?

---

Edit:

The code above has been abstracted as I believed the problem could be explained on a more abstract level.

I cannot recall the first case when it bit me, but now the Observable comes from ngrx store, so it's basically something along these lines:

```
this.text$ = store.let((state$: Observable<State>) => {
  return state$.select(state => state.text);
});
```

Comment: Can you post more code? Like how is `SomeObservable` created? And what change detection strategy have you put on your component?

Comment: No you HAVE to run changedetection yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445670/angular-2-view-will-not-update-after-variable-change-in-subscribe/40707669#40707669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you shouldn't subscribe to the observable when using `async`.
It's why `async` is that awesome. It handles both `subscribe` AND `unsubscribe` when your component is initialized/destroyed.

**So instead of :**
JS

```
myTextSubscription$ = SomeObservable.subscribe();
```

HTML

```
{{ myTextSubscription$ | async }}
```

**You should rather have :**
JS

```
myTextSubscription$ = SomeObservable;
```

HTML

```
{{ myTextSubscription$ | async }}
```

I'd like to clarify the use of $ in your variable name :
 - an observable should be suffixed with '$'
 - when you use subscribe, you do not get an observable

**With respect of convention :**
JS

```
let someObservable$ = ...;
```

HTML

```
{{ someObservable$ | async }}
```

**Remember that :**
- you need to unsubscribe *manually* from an observable when you use subscribe to it, except from the router and http)
- when you have a `.subscribe`, the value returned is of type `Subscription` (which means you can unsubscribe from it)

So here's an overview of a cleaner structure (without using async pipe) :

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...html',
  styleUrls: ['...css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private myText: string;
    private myTextSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // I assume here that you declared an observable called "someObservable"

        this.myTextSubscription = someObservable$.subscribe(text => this.myText = text);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // as our observable is not coming from router or http, we need to manually
        // unsubscribe in order to avoid memory leaks

        this.myTextSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

EDIT 1:
With your updated example, here's how you should use it with @ngrx :

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...html',
  styleUrls: ['...css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private text: string;
  private textSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private store$: Store<State>) {
    this.textSub =
        store$.select('yourState')
            .subscribe((state: State) => this.text = state);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.textSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want more info on ngrx/store or even ngrx/effects, here's what helped me a lot : This [tutorial](http://bodiddlie.github.io/ng-2-toh-with-ngrx-suite/) and once you feel comfortable enough, read the *awesome* code of this [repo](https://github.com/teropa/harmonics-explorer) (from Teropa).

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if `SomeObservable` is somehow initialized outside Angulars zone or uses some API that is not coverted by zone.js.

We would need to see how `SomeObservable` is exactly constructed to know for sure.

Comment: Now we need to see how and where `store` is initialized and where it comes from (what package, GitHub repo).

Comment: The app has been scaffolded following the [ngrx example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app), so `store` comes from the StoreModule

Comment: That should work. Sorry, no idea why it doesn't for you. Is this in Chrome or some other browser?