# Angular 4: Update template variable after API call

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-observables

I have a Component-directive that I use to show a div with some information.

This component is called **SitesComponent** and is included in a page. The main behavior of the **SitesComponent** is fine, except for this:

- I have an API call to a backend where I return some data, the backend call is executed well and I received the information but the variable **is not updated on the template**

This is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyApi } from '../../myapi';

@Component({
  selector: 'sites-component-widget',
  templateUrl: './sites-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sites-component.scss'],
})
export class SitesComponent {
    data: any = [];
    constructor(private api: MyApi}

    ngOnInit() {
        var _ = this
          this.api.company_sites(this.companyId).subscribe(
            response => {
                //this.data = response; 
                this.data = [1,2,3]; 
            },
            error => {
              console.log("error")
            }
          )
        }        
    }
}
```

I tried to update the variable **data** using the received response and also using static data. The UI is never updated with the changes inside the API call.

I'm using angular http client:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
```

But it didn't work neither

- What I'm doing wrong ?

I read about using observables or promises for the API, I tried both ways and I couldn't find a solution... My UI is never updated when I update the variable inside the **.subscribe()** or **.then()** functions

**EDIT:**
I forgot to add my html, but as far it is just 3 lines:

```
<div class="sites-online-widget">
    **{{data}}**
</div>
```

### Summary of my issue:

If I do this the variable **is updated** on the template

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.data = [1,2,3,4]
}
```

but when I do this, the variable **is not updated** on the template:

```
ngOnInit() {
    var _ = this
      this.api.company_sites(this.companyId).subscribe(
        response => {
            this.data = [1,2,3]; 
        }
      )}        
}
```

## Final Edit

Found a solution that worked in another question, I tried to close this one.

The question that solved my issue was this:

[Angular 2 View will not update after variable change in subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445670/angular-2-view-will-not-update-after-variable-change-in-subscribe/38449169)

3 basic steps:

```
// Import ChangeDetectorRef
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

// Add ChangeDetectorRef to constructor
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

// Call markForCheck at the end of the subscribe function
this.cd.markForCheck();
```

My code ended like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyApi } from '../../myapi';

// 1
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sites-component-widget',
  templateUrl: './sites-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sites-component.scss'],
})
export class SitesComponent {
    data: any = [];
    constructor(
      private api: MyApi,
      // 2
      private cd: ChangeDetectorRef}

    ngOnInit() {
        var _ = this
          this.api.company_sites(this.companyId).subscribe(
            response => {
                this.data = response; 
                // 3
                this.cd.markForCheck()
            },
            error => {
              console.log("error")
            }
          )
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your html

Comment: @Llai yes, I forgot to add it but right now I'm just showing the value inside the variable

Comment: can you do an `ngif`  ? Show the div if the data is not null or something?

Comment: I did, data is initialized to empty array `[]`. If I do ngIf to show if data is empty, it is, even after receiving the response. Like I said, it seems the main issue is that the variable **data** is not being updated inside the **susbcribe** method. And I'm 100% sure the code goes inside the subscribe method because I'm printing the result of the API

Comment: The main issue is the value does not updating in your html. You have the array initialized as `[]` so your html is rendering an empty array. So do an `ngif` to show your div only when the array is NOT empty.

Comment: I already did, and the variable is not getting updated, the div is always hidden

Comment: try this `Observable.interval(10000)
    .takeWhile(() => !stopCondition)
    .subscribe(i => { 
        // change variable data here 
    })` and see if the data change

Comment: also, datatype of `data` shouldn't by of `any`.  It should be an array. And could you please tell me what condition are you checking in `ngif`. 
And there are no console errrors whatsoever?

Comment: I need a variable with empty list, to store the array returned by the backend. My issue is that the template is not updated when I change the value of **data** inside the **subscribe** method of the API. On the ngif I was checking the length of the array, no console errors, if I change the variable elsewhere, the ngIf behaves as expected

Comment: int the array as undefined and check that instead

Comment: do you resolve the problem?

Comment: Nope, still struggling with it. I initialized to undefined but it was the same

Answer (score 1):

implement OnInit

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class SitesComponent implements OnInit {}
```

Comment: My code from `ngOnInit()` is being executed. I get the response of the API, but the UI is not updated when the variable **data** changes inside the **subscribe** method. Is that right ? I tried adding the code you suggested but nothing changes

Comment: pls show the html code, and check if response is not undefined, `console.log(response)`.

Comment: I'm 100% sure the response is not empty, I already checked that, the response has data, I printed it to console before posting the question. The problem is when I change the **data** variable inside the subscribe method nothing happens on the UI (even when I do `this.data = [1,2,3]`)