# ngIf not updating DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I have a variable `isLTEavailable` in my ts file inside a function. When the function is called, based on the a condition, `isLTEavailable`'s value changes and is logged correctly, but for some reason, it is not being updated in the DOM.

Here's my ngif condition:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" *ngIf="isLTEavailable">
```

Here's my ts function:

```
console.log("Lte --", lte_id)

if (lte_id != undefined) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("lte_customer_id", lte_id.toString())
    this.isLTEavailable = true;
    console.log("isLTEavailable -----> ", this.isLTEavailable)
} else {
    sessionStorage.setItem("lte_customer_id", 'n/a')
    this.isLTEavailable = false;
    console.log("isLTEavailable -----> ", this.isLTEavailable)    
}
```

I printed the variable using string interpolation as well and it always shows true as its value even though console updates correctly.

P.S. `isLTEavailable` is initialized as true.

Comment: have you tried with isLTEavailable == true ??

Comment: yes i did. Still the same issue

Comment: can you provide working demo, i need to see your condition and where are you calling the function

Comment: Where are you running this function?

Comment: Just display the value using interpolation i.e. `{{isLTEavailable}}` above the list item and make sure the value is getting changed.

Comment: @Arcteezy As mentioned, I did dispay using interpolation but it is not being updated. It is being logged correctly though.

Comment: @jae.phoenix In my component's .ts file

Comment: Yes, but are you doing it in a lifecycle hook or a custom function?

Comment: @jae.phoenix, custom function

Comment: you need to provide outlook to us to understand your code logic

Comment: I think `lte_id` is not set, thus isLTEavailable is false, thus its not shown...

Comment: are you sure that you have bound the scope of the function to your context? Usually, creating an arrow function solves that. Can you show us how your function signature looks like, and how you invoke it?

Comment: Are you using changeDtection in Your componernt?

Answer (score 4):

According to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445670/angular-2-view-will-not-update-after-variable-change-in-subscribe)

**Change detection** fails on change in a variable inside a **callback** or **subscribe** method.
One could use

```
 ngZone.run(() => { this.isLTEavailable = false })
```

to update the value.
**(or)**
trigger the change detection manually by following

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core'
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){}


//after variable update
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

Let me know if this works. Thanks

Comment: No changes. detectChanges() returns undefined

Comment: have you tried logging it out after the detectChanges() called ?

Comment: yes i did. the function returns undefined and the variable's value changes properly

Comment: could you create a stackBlitz https://stackblitz.com just with the skeleton ??

Answer (score 1):

Make Use of Angular's Observable

In your TS file :

Declare :

```
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
  isLTEavailable : Observable<boolean> ; 

  //and in your function
  console.log("Lte --", lte_id)

  if (lte_id != undefined) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("lte_customer_id", lte_id.toString())
    this.isLTEavailable = new Observable(observer=>observer.next(true));
  } else {
    sessionStorage.setItem("lte_customer_id", 'n/a')
    this.isLTEavailable = new Observable(observer=>observer.next(false));
  }
```

Then in your HTML Use the ASYNC pipe :

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown" *ngIf="isLTEavailable | async">
```

Here is the working example i have put together for you to look at :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v4dvx6

Comment: That's always setting it to false for some reason even though going inside the if condition and not else

Comment: The answer i posted is an working example. i post the stackblitz for the same

Comment: Wasn't me @Wisely. My reputation is too low for my vote to account for a change anyway.

Comment: Ok, Ill try to put a working example for you, make sure your code is put together right.

Comment: Can you take a look at the example i posted?

Comment: @UjjwalSharma Is it working? don't look at _scalar values in the log. I've updated the code for the console.logs.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Seems to me this is an issue beyond the scope of this question. It might be due to some other mistake I made elsewhere. I'll debug and let you know. What I'm stumped about is why the interpolation is not working since it is one way data binding and should work.

Comment: Yes the issue seems to lie else where

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for having a healthy discussion here. I found the issue with my code and fixed it and now the interpolation works as expected. The issue was the initialisation of isLTEavailable variable inside the ngOnInit which resulted it in being updated back to the original state whenever the function was called. Again, thanks for helping me out. I got to learn about the changeDetection function and learned about using Observables as an alternative from your answers. Thank you. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ChangeDetectorRef https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef like this `this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`,

```
constructor(private _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {

}

//IN YOUR FUNCTION
if (lte_id != undefined) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("lte_customer_id", lte_id.toString())
    this.isLTEavailable = true;
    console.log("isLTEavailable -----> ", this.isLTEavailable)
    this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()

} else {
    sessionStorage.setItem("lte_customer_id", 'n/a')
    this.isLTEavailable = false;
    console.log("isLTEavailable -----> ", this.isLTEavailable)
    this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()   
}
```

Comment: No changes. detectChanges() returns undefined

Comment: Can you make an example of the problem at stackblitz? @UjjwalSharma