# Angular 9 - View will not update after variable change in subscribe

Tags: angular, angular9, subscribe

I could not make it persistent behavior in HTML part while using subscribe to the http client in the Anglar 9. I tried following stackoverflow posts -

1. [Angular 2 View will not update after variable change in subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445670/angular-2-view-will-not-update-after-variable-change-in-subscribe)
2. [Angular 6 View is not updated after changing a variable within subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50519200/)

Following is the code what I am trying

```
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  list: any[];
  unsubscribe$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone,private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     return this.http
            .get(environment.apiBaseUrl + url, this.getOptions())
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
            .subscribe(()=>{
                this.ngZone.run(()=>{
                   this.list = response.data;
                })
                this.list = response.data;
                this.changeRef.detectChanges();
                this.changeRef.markForCheck();
            });

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }


}

// Nothing working for me.
```

Comment: Can you please reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: @yurzui its in my code .... when i hard refresh then it works....

Comment: That's good that you can see it in your code but it is hard for us to reproduce

Comment: what is  in " .pipe(takeUntil(unsubscribe))" - unsubscribe named variable? have you checked in subscribe that it works? A lot of mess in the code here...

Comment: @TonyMarko sorry it is this.unsubscribe$, to prevent the memory leak, yes subscribe is working here.

Comment: http it's a service in constructor, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onInit` function should be like this, if you use `onPush` strategy:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
     return this.http
            .get(environment.apiBaseUrl + url, this.getOptions())
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
            .pipe(retry(3), catchError(this.handleError));
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.list = response.data;
                this.changeRef.markForCheck();
            });

  }
```

Comment: If it's not working, show your component decorator and the template,

Comment: I already tried all combination of... I have not set any strategy for changeDetection

Comment: I recommend you use async pipe instead of subscription. Anyway without working code, it's impossible to recommend anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think u should make ur life easier by using [async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipes.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    let urURl = 'https://reqres.in/api/products';
     this. list$ = this.http
            .get(urURl)

  }
```

app.component.html

> {{list$|async|json}}

I have created a demo for u on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wrpnte?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: will try and let you know

Comment: thanks, code you suggested also worked but in project above pattern is being used. And i do not see how to prevent memory leak.Anyway  you deserve upvote.

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi  if u are looking not to leak memory then async is the best 
u don't have to manage subscriptions, its doing it own it own. u just have to give ur observable.